# create log group and log stream using serverless framework

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I have the following `Terraform` code. How can I implement the same in `Serverless` framework?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "abc" {
  name = logGroupName
  tags = tags
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "abc" {
  depends_on     = ["aws_cloudwatch_log_group.abc"]
  name           = logStreamName
  log_group_name = logGroupName
}
```

My `Serverless.yml` file looks more like this. Basically I need to create a Log Group and Log Stream with names.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  cfnRole: arn:cfnRole

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
      Resource: 'arn....'

functions:
  handle:
    handler: handler.handle

    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate (2 hours)


resources:
  Resources:
    IamRoleLambdaExecution:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Resources` you have to add [AWS::Logs::LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) and [AWS::Logs::LogStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-logstream.html).

But `tags` on `AWS::Logs::LogGroup` are [not supported](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/77).